# How to retrieve data as JSON and not as HTML from Stack Exchange API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stackexchange-api

Currently I'm working on a Machine Learning Project which analyzes questions on Stack Overflow. I imported requests library and used it to retrieve to questions as follows

```
import requests
data=requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions")
```

I expected to retrieve data as a JSON but I got it as HTML. How to retrieve questions on Stack Overflow as JSON?

Comment: If you want to fetch more questions with one call, increase `?pagesize` parameter (max is 100).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple/quick solution would be.

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow")
print(response.text)
```

Here's the [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/) for the api.There you can find more about getting a key and much more.

What you did, was only to get the html of the `https://stackoverflow.com/questions`, while what you need is access to the API (to get the desired json).

Comment: Is there is a limitation for a unknown user to get data

Comment: [Here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) Here's more info. Unknown (not have an access_token) share a quota with other unknown apps.

Comment: And is the maximum data sets per one request is 30?

Comment: Yes, 30 request/sec per IP. `After that, applications are sorted into two distinct throttles. Those with, and those without, valid access_tokens (obtained via authenticating a user).`

Comment: You have an API quota of 300 (requests that can be done per day per IP) and 10000 (!) if you have an API key.